# Python: yield or return

Tags: python, function, return, yield

So I wrote this piece of code:

```
def character(f):
    #Reads one character(byte by byte) from the given text file
    c = f.read(1)
    while c:
        yield c
        c = f.read(1)
```

I want this value to be parsed in the below function. When I run this code nothing happens. There are no errors but no output is shown too. `dbc_cabin_read` does reach the counter value of 30 but nothing gets printed. I think the program doesn't enter the loop.

```
def dbc_cabin_read(f):
    try:
        f.seek(0,0)
        ctr = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            ctr += 1
            if ctr == 30:                 
                for c in character(f):
                    print(c, sep="", end="")
                break

    finally: 
        f.close()
```

In `character(f)`, if I use `return` instead of `yield` a Type Error occurs:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Suggestion: Use an IDE like PyCharm or try `pdb` to debug the code and find out if the loop really is entered

Comment: Also, how are you running this code? Can you show an example input file? For more information, please make a [mcve]

Comment: `f.readlines()` reads the entire file. There's nothing left for `f.read(1)` to read.

Comment: `line` is reading from `f`, but so is `character()`.  This is almost certainly not right...

Comment: @Barmar - In that case all I need to do is set the cursor back to 0, right?

I changed the following:for line in f.readlines():
            ctr += 1
            f.seek(0)

Even now the same is happening.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using Virtual Studio Code. Did the debugging no errors.

Answer (score 3):

`f.readlines()` reads the entire file. If you just want to read the first 30 lines, you can call `f.readline()` in a loop. Then you can use your generator to continue reading from the file at that point.

```
for _ in range(30):
    f.readline()
for c in character(f):
    print(c, sep="", end="")
```

Comment: I understand the issue now. 
I still have a question - What exactly happens when I use Yield and what happens when I use return? Why is there an error when I use Retrn?

Comment: @GarvitGugnani That depends where you put the return and what you returned. But `NoneType object is not iterable` suggests you have returned just put `return` and not `return c`, for example. which would have been an int

Comment: @GarvitGugnani See [The yield keyword explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/)